# Software Configuration and .ebextensions priorities

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux

Last week Amazon Linux v2.7.0 was released. After update to this version Software Configuration in the web console disappeared. Because of that change we had to quickly move to .ebextensions file configuration instead. We use file like this one below.

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:tomcat:jvmoptions" :
    Xms: 512m
    Xmx: 1024m
    XX:MaxPermSize: 256m
    JVM Options: "--add-modules java.xml.bind"
```

After few days Amazon surprisingly released Amazon Linux v2.7.1 making these options available again. So now we have the same thing configured in two places. What is the priority of them? We see they are picked randomly. Sometimes from our file sometimes from the web console.

In my opinion it should update the web console configuration after every deployment but it does not :(

[image]

Comment: It would depend on how you are deploy your application. Are you using eb cli or aws cli?

Comment: I use aws eclipse plugin to deploy my apps.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't use this plugin. But I had a lot of problem with eb cli because of options precedence - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html Now we use only aws cli